# Has the size of the text in TeX.SE decreased?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

For about a week I have noticed some small worsening on the visualization of the site TeX.SE.

[image]

As you can see from the rectangles that I highlighted with the color orange, the text has a smaller size than usual. I wanted to understand if this is a problem that only concerns me or some I have noticed this difference. Thank you.

Comment: There were some design tweaks recently (I noticed it when the review landing page https://tex.stackexchange.com/review looked different, but error messages, for example for voting, also look different now), maybe the size of the text you mention was also changed. Since this is site-wide you probably need to take that up with https://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SE is in the process of integrating their own design guideline, [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/using-stacks) to the site, so expect some sudden UI-related changes in the future.

Comment: interesting questinon, and the earlier comments *do* address the prose.  but i misunderstood the statement of the question, thinking it was a qhestion of "should it be done?" rather than "has something already happened?" -- please clarify.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done! I have edit my question hoping it's clearer than before.

Comment: but the title is still confusing.  maybe something like "Hhas the size of the text in tex.se decreased?"  (but thanks for sharpening up the text.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Excuse me very much for my delay.